# Header: text/icons positioning and keeping text/icons inside header when zooming out in different browsers

Tags: html, css, header, cross-browser, position

I'm very new to HTML and CSS. Right now i'm trying to create a header, you can see the demo [here](http://cssdeck.com/labs/kl2deulh)

Basically I want the text and icons from "Login" move to the right side of header so it looks more like this:

[image: header]

I also want the text and icons positioned inside the header when you zoom out in different browser.

I've tried to position the `a` tags to the right but it keeps going outside of the header on different browser. I've also tried to create a `div class` for the left part and the right part in the header, but some how the text and icons keeps going out of the header in Safari and Chrome.

Is there any simple solution for these two problems?

Here is the full code for the header.

HTML:

```
<header id="header">
    <span class="free-shipping">Free Shipping</span>
    <span class="free-returns">Free Returns</span>
    <span class="same-day-dispatch">Same-day Dispatch</span>
    <a class="login" href="#" alt="Login">Login</a>
    <a class="create-account" href="#" alt="Create Account">Create Account</a>
    <a class="language-icon" href="#" alt="Choose your language">Language</a>
    <a class="delivery-country-icon" href="#" alt="Choose your delivery country">Delivery Country</a>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
/* ------------------ TOP HEADER ------------------ */

    #header {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
      background: #f5f5f5;
      height: 45px;
      white-space: nowrap;
      width: 1024px;
    }

    .free-shipping {
      background-image: url("images/shipping.png");
      background-position: left center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      font-size: 11px;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding-left: 23px;
      margin-left: 15px; 
    }
    .free-returns {
      background-image: url("images/returns.png");
      background-position: left center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      font-size: 11px;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding-left: 23px; 
    }
    .same-day-dispatch {
      background-image: url("images/dispatch.png");
      background-position: left center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      font-size: 11px;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding-left: 23px;
    }

    .login {
      font-weight: bold;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 11px;
      padding-right: 8px;
      line-height: 45px;
      color: #202020;
    }

    .login:hover { text-decoration: underline; }

    .create-account {
      font-weight: bold;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 11px;
      padding-right: 8px;
      line-height: 45px;
      color: #d13030;
    }

    .create-account:hover { text-decoration: underline; }

    .language-icon {
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      color: #202020;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding-right: 8px;
      padding-left: 27px;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 11px;  
      width: auto;
      height: 24px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      line-height: 25px;
      text-align: right;
      text-decoration: none;
      border-radius: 4px;        
      background: #f5f5f5 url("images/language-sprite.png") no-repeat 0 0 ;
    }

    .language-icon:hover { background: #fff url("images/language-sprite.png") no-repeat 0 -20px ; color: #d13030; }

    .delivery-country-icon {
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      color: #202020;
      padding-right: 9px;
      padding-left: 30px;
      font-weight: bold;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 11px;  
      height: 24px;
      line-height: 25px;
      text-align: right;
      text-decoration: none;   
      border-radius: 4px;     
      background: #f5f5f5 url("images/delivery-country-sprite.png") no-repeat top left ;
    }

    .delivery-country-icon:hover { background: #fff url("images/delivery-country-sprite.png") no-repeat 0 -20px ; color: #d13030; }
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

See in this link an example of this:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Gitjl

I used float to position the elements, one on the left and the other on the right.
Hope it helps you. :D

Comment: Thank you, it worked, however in Chrome the right side goes under the left side when you zoom out. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: It's because in your code in right side you set height, line-height and top margin for some elements. You can add line-hight:45px for left side div and it should be fixed.